# Unable to load a file with ajax load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
        $(function(){
            $("#testdiv").load("sometext.txt",function(){
             alert("Succes");
          });
        });
```

I get the alert but I am not able to see anything in the "#testdiv".The file,sometext.txt is in the same folder.I tried giving it absolute path but i get 404 ,url not found on this server.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what happens when you use normal ajax to load this and save it to the #testdiv?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get exactly what you mean.Do you mean without the alert and function part?if yes,its the same,nothing changes.

Comment: No, use $.ajax or $.get to get the file and put it's contents to the div

Comment: It's the same response.

Comment: What happens when you console.log everything you get from the request?

Comment: $.get("sometext.txt",function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                });  i get this and don' t get anything.

Comment: Also nothing in your network tab? I can't reproduce this

Comment: In my network tab,it's 404 not found

Comment: Then it's not in the same directory... Can you access it normally through the browser?

Comment: The problem is that it isn't finding the file..its in the same folder!

Comment: So you can access it through the browser by going to the URL?

Comment: Yes,just checked!  https://pasteboard.co/HhnHrPz.png a foto of the folder.My page is ajax.html

Comment: Is this function in the HTML or in a file in the ./js folder?

Comment: I found it,my fault!When you asked me if i could access it from browser,yes i did but with a different extention(.txt.txt) i dont know why it happend so i changed the file name in $.get to ".txt.txt" but before that i had given it absolute path and i forgot to remove "/".now everythig is working.Thank you a lot for your help.I appreciate it.Can you make the comment as an answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: ... yup, I'll write you an answer

Comment: I did :P Next time, make sure you can access the file through a browser, or for post requests, use something like Postman or even cUrl to check that they work

Comment: Yes,i am sure i won't do this mistake again. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has several "features" that are built to make their operating system more usable for most people. Hiding the file extension is one of those "features" that often do more harm than how much they help.

Though, as you might know, a file doesn't need a file extension, the first few bytes of the file are used to tell the OS what file type it is, the extension just makes it easy.

When using windows to develop anything, you probably want to see the actual name of your files, so make sure to check out one of the guides on how to enable displaying the file extension, like [this one](https://www.howtohaven.com/system/show-file-extensions-in-windows-explorer.shtml).

If you can't GET a file with JS *always* double, or better even tripple check, that the file can be accessed through the browser first.